# Problems on a request with filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on  a filter for à request in mongodb, one of my filter doesn't work and i don't know why, i will show you the request, the filter and what i exept in the result.

The filter  :

```
 let idTypeProcede = await getTypeProcedeId(filtre.typeProcede);

query = {procedes

    $elemMatch: {
     "typeProcede._id" : idTypeProcede,
   },

   } }
```

On this part, the value of idTypeProcede exist in dataBase and the function getTypeProcessId return an id. So there is my request : (on this request i want to return every gamme if they contain at minimum one or more _id of the typeProcede given by the method getTypeProcedeId)

```
 let gammes = await Gamme.find({...query} )
    .populate({
      path: "creePar",
      model: "Utilisateur",
    })
    .populate({
      path: "modifiePar",
      model: "Utilisateur",
    })
    .populate("projet")
    .populate({
      path: "procedes",
      populate: [
        {
          path: "typeProcede",
          populate: [
            { path: "variablesGlobales" },
            {
              path: "formules",
            },
            {
              path: "typesOperations",
              populate: [
                { path: "formulesTP" },
                { path: "formulesTU" },
                {
                  path: "typesVariablesLocales",
                  populate: { path: "commentaires" },
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              path: "typesVariablesLocales",
              populate: { path: "commentaires" },
            },
            {
              path: "variablesGlobales",
              populate: {
                path: "valeurs",
              },
            },
            {
              path: "tauxHoraire",
              populate: {
                path: "valeurs",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          path: "operations",
          populate: [
            {
              path: "typeOperation",
              populate: [
                { path: "formulesTP" },
                { path: "formulesTU" },
                {
                  path: "typesVariablesLocales",
                  populate: { path: "commentaires" },
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              path: "variablesLocales",
              populate: [
                {
                  path: "valeurLabelGamme",
                  populate: { path: "commentaires" },
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    })
    .populate({
      path: "labels",
      populate: [
        {
          path: "valeurLabelGamme",
          populate: { path: "commentaires" },
        },
      ],
    })
    .populate({
      path: "commentaires",
      populate: [
        {
          path: "auteur",
          model: "Utilisateur",
        },
      ],
    });
```

So I exept a certain number of Gamme, but the result is only [], so how can i fix this problem,  i need to change my filter ? For more information my Json file of what i want to search look like this :

```
{ 
procedes : [
{ typeProcede : { 
_id (this is what i want to compare)}
}
]}
```

Comment: I noticed that in `await getTypeProcedeId(filtre.typeProcede);`, it says `filtre` instead of `filter`. It is done in purpose or it is a mistake?

Comment: it's done in purpose, and this part doesn't make problems

Comment: you need to put the Id in `$elemMatch: {
     "typeProcede._id" : idTypeProcede._id,
   }`

Comment: or `await getTypeProcedeId(filtre.typeProcede)._id`

Comment: it Doesn't work this return the same result, i tried many things in therm of request and nothing happended....

Comment: What does `getTypeProcedeId` return?

Comment: An ID of the type Procede.when consol log the value of query, that's, show me the path of what I find with the ID. When I check if the ID the function getIdTypeProcede return, it exist in database, but not in my filter (i find in the right collection) so what can I do